# Unique constraint voilated error in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am using sorter transformation to select distinct and sorted input.

My mapping: source-source qualifier-expression-sorter-target.

I got unique constraint violated error. The Error code is 22050. I tried by setting stop on errors to 0. But, It reflects on result. I have 654 rows in my source table. but, after setting above property, it returns 448 rows. I know, this property is used to reject invalid rows. Is this property removing only duplicates or anything else? it is invalid rows. what are the invalid rows?

Comment: The session log contains all rejected rows and a error returned by the database for each of them. Can you find this information?

Comment: @Marek- I got the information. Thanks.

Comment: Please share what you happened to find, for forum sake!

Comment: @Raja Reddy- Actually, I had set primary key on target table. i was getting duplicate entries in my source table. Thats why, i got this error.

Comment: gotcha now! thanks for your info and time